# Unable to fully install `initramfs-tools` on debian 12 with additional harddisk errors

Tags: debian, boot, grub, initramfs

I am receiving errors/warnings every time the linux kernel is being updated, which has been concerning. It says that `initramfs-tools` is only partially downloaded and that I don't have any space left.

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64
zstd: error 70 : Write error : cannot write block : No space left on device 
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -9 -T0 70
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64
zstd: error 70 : Write error : cannot write block : No space left on device 
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -9 -T0 70
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

- I checked my boot partition and I have only used 82%, leaving me 42MB of space available, which should be more than enough.
- I have been getting these errors since I have updated from Debian 11 (buster) to Debian 12 (bookworm). My current kernel is `6.1.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.55-1 (2023-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Ever since the update I have been also getting "Hard disk Health Warnings" as one can see from the image below popping up now and then, which I don't know whether it has a relation to this issue or not.
  [image]
- I have ran `smartctl` tests on the relevant partitions, but they all pass the test and I haven't had any issues so far...

Another thing I should probably mention, is that every since the upgrade to bookworm, whenever there was a kernel update, I needed to remove the second oldest kernels manually, which I never needed to do before in Buster. For this I run (as root) the commands

```shell
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
```

and then of course

```shell
update-initramfs
update-grub
```

Now, since having the issue with `initramfs-tools` after running `update-grub` I get the following error.

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: .background_cache.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-13-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-13-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

I am quite concerned since this problems are regarding my boot partition and linux-kernels. Does anyone know a fix? And are the Hard disk warnings a related issue I should be concerned about?

Comment: looks like /boot is full. 42 MB is very very little.

Comment: The total size is of /boot is 235M, used: 181M and available: 42M. And the package `initramfs-tools` seems to be only 116k when uncompressed. So I think 42M should be more than enough no?

Comment: my initrds are between 39 and 45 MB in size, and the kernel image is about 14 MB. So, no, trust the error message: you don't have enough space, `cannot write block : No space left on device ` You don't need the initramfs tools to boot, you need the initial ram disk image.

Comment: You can change the settings from "most" to "dep" to get a smaller initramfs file built. But there's the risk that something isn't detected and makes the boot fail . man initramfs.conf

Comment: Ah never mind even with dep it's still ~ 40ish

Comment: @MarcusMüller so would you recommend to repartition my boot partition using i.e. gparted?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have been down this same path recently and unfortunately I do not have good news. In my case I ended up rebuilding the machines (yes, more than one) from bare metal after Debian released kernel 6.1.0-15-amd64 was issued. (Personally, I would like to tell the individual or group that broke Debian "stable" tell what the word "stable" means!) I was lucky, I broke machines I had just began building. My laptop is always manually updated (i.e. not running unattended updates.) So manual updating saved my laptop from this disaster. Shame on Debian for letting "stable" be broken!